# jqPlot - Replot w/o Page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, data-visualization

I'm trying to change the color of the bars on a bar graph in jqPlot. I found the replot method which successfully changes the color of the bars but it seems to be initiating a page refresh which then just resets the options to what they were when the page initially loaded. What am I doing wrong here?

**Replot:**

```
 $('#changeColor1').click(function(){
    plot1.replot({ 
        seriesDefaults: { 
            rendererOptions: { 
                varyBarColor: true 
            } 
        }, 
        seriesColors: [ "#4bb2c5", "#c5b47f", "#EAA228", "#579575", "#839557", "#958c12", "#953579", "#4b5de4", "#d8b83f", "#ff5800", "#0085cc"] 
    });
});
```

**Chart Config:**

```
  plot1 = $.jqplot('Chart1', [s1], {
    // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
    animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
    title: {
        text: 'Chart1',
        fontSize: '15pt',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
        rendererOptions: {
            barDirection: 'horizontal',
            barWidth: 15,
            color: 'rgb(230,230,245)'
        }
    },

    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
    },

    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            pointLabels: { show: true },
            max: tcMax,
            min: 0,
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                fontSize: '12px',
                formatter: function(format, value){
                    return parseInt(value / 1000) + ' K'; 
                },
            },
        },
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: Ticks,
            tickOptions: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                },
            },
        }//end yaxis
     },

    highlighter: { 
        showTooltip: true,
        tooltipLocation: 'e',
        sizeAdjust: 0,
        tooltipContentEditor: tooltipContentEditor,
    },

    grid: {
        background: 'rgb(72, 102, 137)',
    },
});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <table style="width:100%;">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td><button id="changeColor1">Change Color</button></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <div id="Chart1" style="height:900px;width:700px; "></div>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Why would calling a method with options cause a full page refresh? that doesn't make any sense unless that was the whole purpose of the method. Are you sure the refresh isn't happening because you're clicking on an Anchor tag with an `id="changeColor1" href=""`?

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening. I am using a `<button>` tag so its not an anchor tag causing the issue.

Comment: is the button in a form? does the form have a submit button already? If no submit button is present, the first button that is found will be the submit button.

Comment: If you comment out replot, does it still refresh?

Comment: The button is within a form causing the refresh.... How can I prevent this?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` corrected the issue. Kevin B if you want to post this as the answer I will accept it since you identified the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a form with a single button, that one button will be a submit button unless you give it `type="button"`. However, it's probably safer to just use `e.preventDefault` since you don't intend for the button to do anything other than your click event.

```
$('#changeColor1').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```